# Xamarin : How to create a built-in application

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I saw theres some apps like samsung app or other apps that exist even the android has been totally format or reset.

How does this work and how to create this kind of apps? Does it related to OnCreate() Method?

Comment: AFAIK these apps are preloaded on the device by the manufacturer - I don't  think there is anything particularly special about the app itself that does this